# Pop-Up Punk Party

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I'm hoping someone can please help me.

My friend was able to snag a couple of wrist bands to an underground gig but I don't know where it is or how to get in. He was whispering when he handed me a poster and the band, trying to keep it between us. The downside was that I didn't hear everything he said. Now I can't get hold of him and the gig is tonight!

He said something about the block of text on the poster, I noticed his copy had letters marked out and numbers jotted down the edge. Here's what mine says:

> 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

The text looks different on the poster, I'm not sure if that helps?

This is my copy of the poster:

> [image]

He also said that if I had trouble or forgot what to do, that the wrist band should jog my memory. It doesn't.

This is my band:

> [image]

I'm hoping someone can make sense of this and help me translate with the information given. If not, I'll be missing out.

> I need location specifics and a password to give at the door.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I think I've got it. Thanks Rubio and GentlePurpleRain for the upfront legwork and deciphering the morse code!

**Solution:**

> Location: Door marked X, Opposite Sid's Records, Freeman St 
>  Password: COMETBUS

**Decoded message from poster:**

> DOOR MRKD X OPP SIDS RECODS FREEMAN ST PASS COMETBUS

**How to decode:**

> 1. Ignore all letters in the block of text other than the regular font lowercase a's, b's, and c's.
>  2. Start counting the a's between every b, using the wristband morse code hint to decipher: FIRST (a) is key, SECOND (b) is end char, THIRD (c) are breaks
> 3. The number of a's represents a letter in the alphabet (A1Z26 encoding).
> Bonus notes:
>  Rearranging bold/italic letters: icrgspneoa = "ignore caps"
>  Decoding just the numbers in the poster yields "Red Herring". (i.e. false clue)

Comment: Yep! You've solved it completely, even the superfluous information :D

Comment: Bounty awarded, well done :)

Comment: Nice job! I couldn't make sense of the band directions - glad you could!

Comment: @Rubio the bold/italic letters you discovered may have helped narrow that down ;)

Comment: Bold/italic letters are: icrgspneoa = ignore caps.  Thanks for the bounty @BreakingMyself. This was a fun puzzle!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you enjoyed it :)

Answer (score 5):

**Partial solution**

Just getting started ...

The band list:

> * FE(A)T *           (the "A" is in a red circle)
>  ------------
>  CRYPTO-CATS
>  ANTIROT(13)
>  THE JOE
>  PANTOLIANO
>  EXPERIENCE
>  BINARY-
>     DENIAL
>  SALAD
>     FACE
>  SPECIAL
>  GUESTS:
>  THE RED
>  HERRINGS!!

`The text looks different on the poster, I'm not sure if that helps?`

> Unless I've missed something, the correct transcription including the hard-to-see italics on the poster is:
>  `DaGaJM18aKabaOaUaaVaXaa`***i***`aaaPBaEaaXaabAaWaSaNaXa`***c***`aaaLLaIaQ`
>  `TaaaFaaC5baaXaaHaaTaaRaaXaaaaaaaXa`***r***`bcaaQaaaaXaaTaaaXaabaa`
>  `aQaaaXaaa4aaaaaaOaaabaMaaaaXaaUaaaabaaRaabcaaaXaaaaXaaaAa`
>  `aaHaaaaBaa8aXaaKaabcaaDaaIaa`***g***`aaaaXaaaaabaaaaaaQaaXaaBaaAa`
>  `aaabaaIaaaO5aaVaaTaGaXaaaaabcaPaaOaaaXaaAaaaMaaaaaaNaabaa`
>  `aaEaaaaabaaX18aabaaaaaaEaaaXaaaCaaaaaaabcaXaaaaaFaaaaaRaa`
>  `GaaaCaabaaaJaa18baaabaaVaLaaaaaHaaaaJaaabaaXaIabaaaMaaFaa`
>  `UaaTaaaJa`***s***`aaaMaa9LabcaaaaaRabaaaTaIaHaaNaaaPaaaaaEaaaba`***p***`a`
>  `aIaSabaBaOaaabaaR14aaaaAaaSaaOaaababaaaaaOaaXaRaWaaNaaabc`
>  `aFaaaKaaaUaaaaRaaWa6aDaaXaabaaaaaJPaaaXaDaa`***n***`aaaNaaaaLaabc`
>  `aaaaaaSaaaHaaaKaBaaabAPabaaIaaXaaaCaaaBaXaaJaaa`***e***`aaabaaaGa`
>  `aaaaaSaaKaaTTaaEaaaKabcXaaabaaXaaOaaa`***o***`aaaaXaaaTabaaXaSaaU`
>  `aaaaWaNaLOLaabaaKaaabaaXaaUaXaaIaaaXaaaRaaaaaFaabaabaaRaa`
>  `aXaJaaaHaaaNaXaaaOaaDaaLabaXaJaDaaaAaaaEaXaaaBaaaFaaSabc`***a***

`the wrist band should jog my memory`

> The wristband has Morse code, which translates to:
>  FIRST IS KEY SECOND END CHARACTER THIRD BREAKS
>
>  @GentlePurpleRain points out in comments that the numbers on the end of the band, 11 5 25,
>  are A1Z26 codes for **KEY**.

Comment: That was fast! You may have missed a bit. Good luck with the rest.

Comment: As @BreakingMyself indicated, you missed a word.  It should be FIRST IS KEY SECOND ***END*** CHARACTER THIRD BREAKS.

Comment: Also note that 11 5 25 on the end of the wristband translates to **`KEY`**.

Comment: @Rubio Did you manage to make any further progress? I'm hoping my 'baked-in' hints are enough but please let me know if you need to be pointed in the right direction (although you've made good work so far, so probably don't need it).